# Find largest match string in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to know how to find the longest match string from a given string.

For instance lets say I have this string `1122334455` in `table_a` and have a `table_b` with a column containing those following values:

```
'11'
'112'
'1122'
'112233'
'1122335455'
```

The desire match of the string `1122334455` is `112233`.

> Is there any function or query that could be use the desire output?

Answer (score 1):

Match the string using like operator and sort results by length:

```
select *
from table_b
join table_a on table_a.str like concat('%', table_b.str, '%')
order by char_length(table_b.str) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think your solution will work when we have 2 string but in this case it's 2 columns meaning array of strings in each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can join using the `LIKE` operator and then use a Window Function to identify which match for each `tablea` string is the largest from `tableb`.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT tablea.yourstring, 
      tableb.yourotherstring, MAX(LENGTH(tableb.yourotherstring)) OVER (PARTITION BY tablea.yourstring) as maxlength
    FROM tablea
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb 
        ON tablea.yourstring LIKE concat('%', tableb.yourotherstring, '%')  
  )
WHERE LENGTH(yourotherstring) = maxlength;
```

I believe Google is introducing the Qualify clause (available in Snowflake and Teradata currently) in a future release and currently available in pre-release, where this becomes a little easier to write:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb 
    ON tablea.yourstring LIKE concat('%', tableb.yourotherstring, '%')
QUALIFY LENGTH(tableb.yourotherstring) = MAX(LENGTH(tableb.yourotherstring)) OVER (PARTITION BY tablea.yourstring)
```

Comment: Your solution is good but since there are millions of rows in the columns its taking to much time to get the results. Do you have any other suggestion to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (BigQuery)

```
select col_a as pattern, col_b as match
from table_a, unnest(generate_array(1, length(col_a))) pos
join table_b
on starts_with(substr(col_a, pos), col_b)
where true
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by col_a order by length(col_b) desc)
```

if applied to dummy data as in your question

```
with table_a as (
  select '1122334455' col_a union all 
  select '1123334455'
), table_b as (
  select '11' col_b union all
  select '112' union all
  select '1122' union all
  select '112233' union all
  select '1122335455' 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Note: I purposely NOT using LIKE as it is quite expensive string function, which can be quite expensive on big volumes ...

Comment: Your solution is good but since there are millions of rows in the columns its taking to much time to get the results. Do you have  any other suggestion to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which does abandon matching strings as soon as there is a mismatch between characters at the same position between two strings:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION max_overlap(a STRING, b STRING)
   RETURNS STRING
   LANGUAGE js AS r"""
     let out = '';
     for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] == b[i]){
           out += a[i];
        }
        else {
           break;
        }
     }
     return out;
   """;


select a_str, b_str
from table_a 
cross join table_b 
order by length(max_overlap(a_str, b_str)) desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think your solution will work when we have 2 strings but in this case it's 2 columns meaning array of strings in each column.